# ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database - Nest Js

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de chat y el backend lo estoy haciendo con Nestjs. 
Me he quedado en la parte de hacer la conexion a la base de datos.

Lo que estoy usando es MYSQL y TypeORM.
Paso las versiones de cada uno por si se necesita:

- "typeorm": "^0.3.9"
- "mysql2": "^2.3.3"
- "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1"
- "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13"

Leí varias posibles soluciones y las apliqué pero ninguna me funciona.

El error es el siguiente:

```
[Nest] 7948  - 18/09/2022 15:39:50 ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database.
```

Luego de 10 intentos sale este error:

```
[Nest] 7948  - 18/09/2022 15:39:53   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Option "database" is not set in your connection options, please define "database" option in your connection options or ormconfig.json
```

Hice lo que plantea el error, me fije primero si "database" estaba mal escrito, pero estaba bien. Luego cree el archivo ormconfig.json y puse los datos de configuración de conexión, y tampoco funciona. Probé poniendo synchronize en false o no poner el puerto, y antes de correr "npm run start:dev" cree la base de datos - por lo que la contraseña y el usuario de mysql son correctos, pero no ha dejado de salir ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este momento tengo asi los dos archivos:

**ormconfig.ts**

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
export const ormconfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
      type: "mysql",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3306,
      username: "root",
      password: ...,
      database: "chatapp_database",
      entities: [__dirname + "/../utils/typeorm/entities/*.ts"],
      synchronize: true,
    };
```

Nota: Las entidades están creadas en "src/utils/typeorm/entities/". 
Solo tengo creado el usuario, lo muestro por si el error es de este archivo:

**User.ts**

```
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column()
  @Exclude()
  password: string;
}
```

Por ultimo, tengo en **app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { ormconfig } from "./config/ormconfig";  // <-- Aca importo la configuración

import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { UserModule } from "./users/user.module";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: ".env.development" }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Espero alguno me pueda orientar.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar para descartar, poner la configuracion directamente en el import asi

```
@Module({imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(
    {
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "tutorial",
    "entities": [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')],
    "synchronize": true,
}
```

de todos modos te recomiendo si tienes un tiempo checar este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICToemTgK1Q&t=134s) donde explican el proceso de conectarse a una base de datos con typeOrm , quizas vez donde estas cometiendo el error.

saludos, espero ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso yo lo incluyo dentro de mi app.module.ts de esta manera:

```
 TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  logging: true, // Habilita el registro de consultas SQL en la consola
  synchronize: true,
  // logging: 'all', // Habilita registros detallados
}),
```